# Switching apartments & the correct way to exercise notice period with current landlord?

Tags: law, rent, landlord

I'm in the process of signing the contract with another apartment, but the owner of the apartment I currently live in is not responding.

I've sent the current owner an email on 6th November and there is a 30 days notice period. I need to move on 1st December. Recently I tried to contact him again by email, phone and SMS, no answer yet.

The future owner wants me to sign the contract tomorrow and I don't know what reason to use to delay this until the current owner gives me a reply.

It would be great if you could help with any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a lease right now? what does it say?

Comment: Send him a formal, signed letter? This is probably what you should have done in the first place. Depending on your country you should be able to send it registered post (tracked) with a delivery notification. If he doesn't get in touch, you then at least have some evidence that you've provided the required notice in writing as well as by other means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't specify what country you live in, nor details about your lease.

In Alberta, Canada, if you are month-to-month, you must give at least a full month's notice. In most cases, your rent would be due at the first of the month, so on November 6th, you could only provide notice that you were terminating as of December 31st. As it is not yet the end of November, you can still provide notice that you will terminate your lease at the end of December.

Exactly how you must give notice is not generally specified. It's a good idea to send registered mail, or hand-deliver a letter. Email would likely be legally considered sufficient notice in Alberta, as it is legally binding in other areas, but I'm not a lawyer.

At this point, send a registered letter. Probably by courier, with a tracking number, to the address on your lease. Do it today, because the date of notice is likely to be the date the letter is delivered, not the date you send it.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, I would say that you have not given enough notice to move out on December 1st without penalty or paying through at least December 6th.   You'll want to review your lease to find out how you have to give notice (email? Certified letter? etc.).   You'll also want to review your lease to find out if you miss your desired date, do you only have to pay through the 30 days (until December 6) or does move out have to be on the first of the month and you are stuck until January 1st.

All of these details (and more) change widely between landlords and apartment complexes and even with different lease agreements at the same apartment complex.   I have seen leases where you can't break your lease early without paying for every month you would have been there and I have seen leases where after you have lived there for more than 3 years, you only need to give 15 days notice.

It is very specific to your particular lease.